# Type.GetType return null even when using full assembly qualified type name

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

In the following code fragment, `Type.GetType` on the final line sometimes returns null.

```
string assemblyName = "My.AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
string typeName = "My.Namespaced.ClassName";
Type t1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == typeName &&
                             x.Assembly.FullName == assemblyName);
string qualifiedName = t1.AssemblyQualifiedName; // this result looks sane
Type t2 = Type.GetType(qualifiedName); // returns null
```

As you can see, I'm using the fully qualified name returned by `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`, and as expected, the value of `qualifiedName` is `My.Namespaced.ClassName, My.AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

At some point in my callstack, `Type.GetType` returns the expected type, but then, if we make a call into another assembly, the exact same snippet of code results in `t1` finding the type, but `t2` being null.

There are no generics in play here anywhere, which I understand from @Eris can sometimes result in null values for Type.AssemblyQualifiedName.  In this case, AssemblyQualifiedName is valid.

I see StackOverflow is littered with duplicate questions when people have not used the assembly qualified name, but that's not the case here.

**Update**
I think this question can be boiled down to the following question: In what circumstances, if we have a non-null `Type t` whose `AssemblyQualifiedName` property is a correct combination of typename and assembly, can `Type.GetType(t.AssemblyQualifiedName);` return null?

Comment: I suspect this is something to do with the outer assembly.  I made a new console app which referenced the same inner dll, and everything works fine in that solution.

Comment: Just a little thing: in rows 5 and 6 of your code section, maybe "TypeName" and "AssemblyName" must be lowercase?

Comment: Oops, yeah, just my typo in the question. I was editing the code by hand to make it more standard C# coding standards rather than our insane internal coding standards. The code does actually compile and run.  So it's not that.

Comment: Does the paragraph "At some point in my callstack..." mean that where you run the code is making a difference?  Or does it mean from where the type is being loaded is making a difference?

Comment: I have the same code snippet in two different assemblies. When I run it in assembly A, t2 is non-null.  I then make a call to assembly B from assembly A, but in assembly B, its t2 is null.
Yet in both assemblies, qualifiedName is the exact same value.

Comment: Also, is it possible that you might be trying to load a type from a dynamically loaded assembly?  [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says you could have problems until the assembly is saved to disk.

Comment: Do the 2 assemblies hold a reference on "My.AssemblyName"? Is that that reference the same? I mean, the same version, the same culture, the same public key token...

Comment: Try using one of the `GetType` overloads that throws exceptions. Maybe you'll get more insight into what's happening. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5cf8k43(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JohnCarpenter: Interesting. We recompile assembly A at process start-up I think. I'm not sure whether that's in our process or not (super-large codebase!)

Comment: @MK87: Assembly A contains the type I'm looking for.  Assembly B does not have a reference to assembly A.

Comment: @elchido: Thanks, will try that out.

Comment: Define "recompile assembly A" please

Comment: @elchido That put me on the right track. The error indicated that Type.GetType couldn't load assembly A from disk.  The issue was that assembly A and assembly B were in different directories, which meant that Type.GetType fails to load it.  I had to alter the code in assembly B to use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(...) to find the assembly, and then call GetType on the resulting assembly.  That worked as expected.

Comment: @Eris: Sure, at process start-up, we delete assembly A (and others) from disk, then use file enumeration to discover all .csproj files within the solution folder, and invoke msbuild to recompile then.  After that, we use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(OurNewlyCompiledDLLFilename));` to load them back in.

Comment: @RichardFawcett, I have the same conclusion. Have you found any other workaround instead of scanning all loaded assemblies into AppDomain?

Comment: @LaoR, no sorry.  I've got no further with this, other than calling GetType on the assembly.